# Related to chi-squared functions

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I'm finding difficulty in finding what type of function it is in continuous distributions in probability. Mainly how can I identify whether a function is chi-squared or not?

Answer (score 0):

A $\chi^2$ is simply a particular probability density function (see [wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loi_du_%CF%87%C2%B2))

You can prove that the sum of the square of normal independent variables follows a $\chi ^2$, which explains why it is used so often to do statistical tests on variance. There is not much more to it than that.